# NodeJS Squalize -- Relationships without including at sign in

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequalization and relationships for the users. So for example, a user can be a customer or can be an employee.

I set this through the following way:

```
models.users.find({
        where: { id: id },
        include: [
           models.customers,
        ],
        limit: 1
    }).then(function(result) {

        done(null, result);

    });
```

The main issue is that not all users are customers or employees but it seems the only way to access the relationships is using the `include` at the state of login.

What I want to be able to do is not include the relationship at login and just use `user.customer` and it finds the relationship, similar to what I would do in Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use the [`instance.getAssociation()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/belongs-to/#getassociationoptions-promiseinstance) method in order to retrieve associated model

```
models.users.findById(id).then(function(user){
    user.getCustomer().then(function(customer){
        // here you obtain customer assigned to user with id = 1
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

I suggest you follow your first concept. On login perform the `find` query with `include` option

```
models.users.findById(id, {
    include: [ models.customers ]
}).then(function(user) {
    if ( user.customer ) console.log('User is a customer');
    else console.log('User is not a customer'); 
});
```

In order to define if `user` is a customer you need to perform a query returning the customer object, otherwise you do not have any option to recognise the type of user. I can also suggest you add some `type` field to `user` model which could be some `ENUM` with values like `customer, employee, regular` defining what kind of user it is. It would be set to proper value when creating new instance e.g.

```js
models.users.create(
    {
        name: 'some name',
        customer: {
            // some customer attributes
        },
        type: 'customer'
    }, {
        include: [ models.customers ]
}).then((user) => { console.log(user); });
```

If you follow this way then you can check user's status at any time by accessing `user.type` which would be one of above `ENUM` values.

Comment: Thanks for that, however, can I do this using `req.user.customer` ?

Comment: Depends on how you implemented it. I have updated the answer with my advices